# Problem SLD LineSymbolizer

Tags: geoserver, style, sld, rule

How can I solve this problem with my SLD code for styles. When I do two scale ranges for a one lineSymbolizer to use another color or another thickness they appear twice in the legend of my viewer because I have to separate them into two rules. Can you do this in the same rule?

```
        <Title>Rua</Title>  



          <ogc:Filter>
            <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyName>TIPO_LOGRADOURO</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:Literal>RUA</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          </ogc:Filter>

      <MinScaleDenominator>17000</MinScaleDenominator>  
      <MaxScaleDenominator>36000</MaxScaleDenominator>

      <LineSymbolizer>

        <Stroke>
      <CssParameter name="stroke">#f6efc0</CssParameter>
      <CssParameter name="stroke-width">0.6</CssParameter>
    </Stroke>

      </LineSymbolizer>

     </Rule>


       <Title>Rua</Title>



         <ogc:Filter>
            <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyName>TIPO_LOGRADOURO</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:Literal>RUA</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          </ogc:Filter>


      <MinScaleDenominator>8500</MinScaleDenominator>  
      <MaxScaleDenominator>17000</MaxScaleDenominator>

      <LineSymbolizer>

        <Stroke>
          <CssParameter name="stroke">#e098a9</CssParameter>
      <CssParameter name="stroke-width">1</CssParameter>
    </Stroke>  

      </LineSymbolizer>
```

The legend looks like

[[image: Legenda]]

Comment: Thanks for the reply Ian. But where do I have to make this request? In fact, he wanted to know if he could do that in SLD. See that RUA appears twice in the caption

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass in the (optional) `SCALE` parameter - see the [documentation](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wms/get_legend_graphic/index.html#getlegendgraphic)
for more details.

Answer (score 1):

You could also try using a categorize or recode transform within a single rule to get the style values you need conditioned on geometry or environment attributes.  https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld/tipstricks/transformation-func.html